# Why is Crond unable to find my shell script?

Tags: python, docker, cron, alpine-linux

I have a Dockerfile as below and I am trying to run a python script every 15 minutes but getting the error shown below

```
docker logs 7e1
run-parts: can't execute '/etc/periodic/15min/startjob': No such file or directory
```

I am able to verify that the `run-parts --test` works ok.
The cron files and python files seem to be available in the docker container.

```
docker exec -it 7e1 /bin/sh
/ # run-parts --test /etc/periodic/15min/
/etc/periodic/15min/startjob
/ # ls -lrt /etc/periodic/15min/startjob
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           201 Jul  6 04:09 /etc/periodic/15min/startjob
/ # ls -lrt /app
total 8
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            10 Jul  5 17:36 requirements.txt
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           290 Jul  5 17:38 pyapp2.py
/ #
```

-------Dockerfile-----------

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
COPY cronscript.sh /etc/periodic/15min/startjob
RUN chmod a+x /etc/periodic/15min/startjob
COPY src/ /app
CMD [ "crond", "-l", "2", "-f" ]
```

--------cronscript.sh--------

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "started $(date)" >> /tmp/job.log
echo "Job started: $(date)"
# Add additional instructions
python /app/pyapp2.py
echo "Job finished: $(date)"
echo "ended $(date)" >> /tmp/job.log
```

Any pointers are greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: docker for windows?

Comment: Did it solve your issue? If so please accept the answer to close this topic.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your issue when the script file `cronscript.sh` hasn't proper line endings (e.g. on Windows CRLF instead of just LF).

In case you edited that file on Windows you could check if the following quick & dirty fix within your `Dockerfile` solves your issue:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
COPY cronscript.sh /etc/periodic/15min/startjob
RUN chmod a+x /etc/periodic/15min/startjob

# Quick & dirty fix
RUN dos2unix /etc/periodic/15min/startjob

COPY src/ /app
CMD [ "crond", "-l", "2", "-f" ]
```

Of course the correct way is to fix the line endings within your file from the get go.

In addition you can see the control characters within the file by running
`cat -v /etc/periodic/15min/startjob`
from within you container, e.g. before applying the quick fix above the output on my machine looked like this (notice the `^M`)

```
cat -v /etc/periodic/15min/startjob
#!/bin/sh^M
echo "started $(date)" >> /tmp/job.log^M
echo "Job started: $(date)"^M
...
```